# (Solved) Trying to Bake Texture from multiple materials - Blender baking UV texture problem

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-baking, baking

I'm trying to bake the lighting onto this scene, I believe I did all the steps correctly, but the texture I get when I press Bake just comes out as these diamond-shaped blobs. I tried to google and look around, but I can't find anything.

The model I'm using was made from just a plane so the bottom of it is hollow, it's all joined as one piece, save for a few point lights I put inside the houses with translucent windows as an experiment. I also have 2 sun lamps and some of the windows are using an emission material.

I checked the normals and they all seem right, I switched on Backface Culling for a second to make sure.

Is there something I'm missing in the baking settings or something? Are there things in the scene that aren't compatible with baking? I've never changed it so I'm pretty sure it's set to the default. I followed a tutorial by Blender Guru and it looks like all the same settings, so I don't know what the problem is.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

I added a world color and closed of the bottom of the mesh, the last image is the current baking result and all my settings. A little more of the texture managed to actually bake, but it's grainy and messed up looking.

[image]

I added an image texture node to all my materials and this is what I got now lol

EDIT 2:

Okay, so I added the image texture node to all my material and then I selected the actual mesh in edit mode, then I baked it, and it seems to have actually worked. Now I'm just messing with the clamping and the sampling to get ride of the fireflies and graininess and it seems to have actually worked. So ***problem solved***.

[image]

Comment: Welcome, @fdd. Did you add a world color? It looks like only the interior lights are baked.

Comment: @LeoNas Hi, I just added one and it seems I'm getting the same result. I also closed up the bottom of the model and it seems to have baked a little more of the texture, but not much, and it's grainy and strange looking. https://imgur.com/a/clGqeuL

Comment: @LeoNas nevermind, i figured it out

Comment: @mr-zak ok sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an image texture node to all the materials, select the mesh in edit mode, then bake it